# Can you create new users without entering email, then prompt user upon first login?

Tags: users

I want the site administrator to be able to create a user, submitting only a username and a dummy password.

This information would then be 'manually' sent by the administrator to the user, whom upon their first login, is forced to enter a verification email and change their password.

How can this be done through modules or otherwise?

Answer (score 6):

Use [Force Password Change](http://drupal.org/project/force_password_change) module.

This module allows administrators to force users, by role, individual user, or newly created user, to change their password on their next page load or login, and/or expire their passwords after a period of time.

Comment: Very nice! What about a way around requiring the administrator to enter an email address?  Also then prompting the new user for their email along side the password reset?